# Bind a key combination for GNOME overlay

Tags: fedora, gnome, wayland

Using GNOME 42.3.1 (Wayland) on fedora 36, the default key to launch the GNOME activities overlay is <kbd>Super</kbd>. I'd like to change that to <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd>.

I installed `dconf-editor` and used it to change the value at `org.gnome.mutter.overlay-key` to `Super_L|return` and to `['<Super>Return']`, but these did not have the desired effect. What is the correct syntax for specifying a key combination here?